# Can't generate valid json when serialising backwards relationship in django

Tags: json, django

I'm having trouble serialising the results of this backwards relationship query in json.

I've pasted below the results of the json - it's basically what I want (would be nice to control what fields are there too) but it's full of escape strings and I can't figure out exactly what it is I need to do to generate clean, valid json in the format of my choosing.

Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong please?

```
#models.py
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length="150")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date published', null=True, blank=True)

class BlogImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    parent_blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)

#views.py
q_set = Blog.objects.order_by('-pub_date').prefetch_related('blogimage_set')

items = list()
for q in q_set:

    q_sub_set = q.blogimage_set.all()
    serial_q_sub_set = serializers.serialize('json', q_sub_set)

    item = {
        'id':q.id,
        'title':q.title,
        'slideshow_imgs':serial_q_sub_set
    }
    items.append(item)

#dump repsonse to json
items = json.dumps(items)
print items

#resulting json..
[{"slideshow_imgs": "[{\"pk\": 5, \"model\": \"site.blogimage\", \"fields\": {\"blog\": 3, \"image_description\": \"\", \"image\": \"images/cat-9822.jpg\", \"image_title\": \"\", \"image_alt\": \"\"}}, 
                  {\"pk\": 6, \"model\": \"site.blogimage\", \"fields\": {\"blog\": 3, \"image_description\": \"\", \"image\": \"images/a_cat_2.jpg\", \"image_title\": \"\", \"image_alt\": \"\"}}]",
                   "id": 3, "title": "last"},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with something of this sorts, using  natural keys Serialization helped a lot. 
Doc Link:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys

From the doc you should be doing something like:

```
 >>> serializers.serialize('json', [book1, book2], indent=2,use_natural_foreign_keys=True, use_natural_primary_keys=True)
```